# Remove comma with jquery and add zero after single number

Tags: jquery, wordpress, review

I try to figure out the following situation. For displaying review stars correctly it is important to show the right percentage. So if there a multiple reviews, the output in html is for example:

```
<span style="width:8,2%"></span>
```

If all reviewed items are having the same number, the output is for example:

```
<span style="width:8%"></span>
```

The problem is decimal after the comma. In my opinion the best solution is remove the decimal and the comma after the first number. So in both situations i can add a zero after the first number and get a proper view of the stars.

The solution would be the following:

```
<span style="width:8,2%"></span>
```

into:

```
<span style="width:80%"></span>
```

And

```
<span style="width:8%"></span>
```

into:

```
<span style="width:80%"></span>
```

My code for jquery is this but will only delete the comma and i have then a problem with a single number. I need a zero if there is just one number

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rating__stars').each(function() {
        var string = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(string.replace(",", ""));
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I hope someone can help me with this.